# Explanation on subroutines in C#

Tags: c#

I have started to code in C# winforms . One problem I'm finding is learning about subroutines. In visual basic it was really easy but I'm not sure how it works in C# with public and static and void. If when a user presses a button I want to pull up a subroutine from a class would I have the subroutine as static void or public?  Also would you use public or static for variables in a class that would be used throughout multiple forms?

An example is this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\RAV21001310\\OneDrive\\Database1.accdb;"))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password.Text);
                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        int count = 0;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }

                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");
                        }

                        if (count > 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password");
                        }
                        if (count == 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Username or password incorrect");
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

public class User
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public string Gender;
        public int Age;
        public int TotalPoints;
    }
```

The first block of code is a login form. If I wanted to call it UserLogin() and put it in the user class would I use static or public for it or would I just rename the private void for button click and put that in the user class instead.

Comment: What exactly makes you unsure about it? Is it not knowing what the purpose and the effect of the `static`/`public`/`private`/`void` keywords is, or is it something else that makes it difficult for you to choose?

Comment: Yeah I just don't know when to use the key words. I used the example of the login code so what keywords I would use if I wanted to store it in the class instead of having the whole code under the button click so I can refer to it as UserLogin() only.

Comment: Well, the best way forward i guess is to read up upon those keywords in the C# documentation to learn what purpose/effect they have. Armed with that knowledge, it should then be clear when (or when not) to use this or that keyword/accessiblity modifier. `static`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static, `public`, `private`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels, `void`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void

Comment: If you want/need to know more about other things related to the C# language syntax/keywords, feel free to further peruse the C# language documentation or tutorials like perhaps this one for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace so void is if there is a return value like a function, static is if it's a subroutine and public is if access isn't restricted. So for my one I would use public void UserLogin() and keep variables as public for them to be used throughout the forms?

Comment: `void` means it doesn't return anything. `static` means the method doesn't need instance data and the caller doesn't need an instance to call it. `public` means its accessible outside the class. *"would I have the subroutine as static void or public"* isn't a logical question since those terms aren't mutually exclusive. In answer to *"would you use public or static for variables in a class that would be used throughout multiple forms?"*, you use `public` for the scope and `static` only if you don't need instance data in the method. please read the documentation.